# Save memory by using user space buffer of write function in function-handler directly (Linux, Kernel)?

Tags: c, linux, memory, memory-management, kernel

I have a Linux filesystem with an implementation of the function:

```
 ssize_t (*write) (struct file *file, const char __user *buffer, size_t count, loff_t *pos);
```

Now let's say I want to use the data of the buffer to calculate parity (within the function handling).
I could use

```
copy_from_user(void *to, const void __user *from, unsigned long n)
```

But the problem is that I need to allocate memory for my kernel space pointer first. The amount of data I want to copy is max. about 7.5 MB and min. 512KB. If i use `kmalloc` to allocate memory in kernel it likely fails and I can't even allocate enough memory in front with a memory pool, because somehow that fails, too...

So: what could happen if I just use the pointer from user space in my code?

```
...
     *(dest) ^= *(buf);
...
```

So far it seems to work (for smaller memory regions though).
I don't know how the memory mapping works. Could the user space memory be not contiguous? Could it even be swapped out? Whats the danger? Thx!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access user space memory from the Linux kernel?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10509850/how-to-access-user-space-memory-from-the-linux-kernel)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User space memory shouldn't be used directly in any case.

If your task can be expressed as a *stream processing* of user data, there is no need to allocate kernel memory for accomodate whole user data *at once*.

It is sufficient to allocate memory of smaller size (e.g., 4KB), read the first chunk of user data into it (using `copy_from_user`), process it, read next chunk into same kernel memory, process it and so on:

```
void* dest = kmalloc(4096, GFP_KERNEL); // or use __get_free_pages()
while(count > 0)
{
    int size = count >= 4096? 4096: count;
    copy_from_user(dest, buffer, size);
    <process-data-in-dest>
    count -= size;
    buffer += size;
}
```