# Reading the contents of a user-space page from Kernel Module

Tags: linux, memory, module, kernel

Is this possible to get the contents of an userspace page from kernel module?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10509850/how-to-access-user-space-memory-from-the-linux-kernel

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access user space memory from the Linux kernel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10509850/how-to-access-user-space-memory-from-the-linux-kernel)